# Youtube channel embed sizes

Tags: php, javascript, youtube, embed

[image]Ok so basically I used the following Youtube Chanel embed code:

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&amp;up_channel=tomdesigner777&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=390&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

And it embed a tiny blue box with a video slideshow with a horrible blue background, but how do I go about making the video player slightly larger and changing the back ground?... the embed code doesn't let me do anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: nope, this is being coded on my localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it compulsory to use a Google module? You won't get much flexibility is making changes.

Why not use the [YouTube API's JSON](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/view_youtube_jsonc_responses) response? That way you can have total flexibility in getting the video's you want through JavaScript.

Here is the JSON feed for channel you want: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/tomdesigner777/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=5

### Update

Here is the code you can use to get a video from a YouTube user upload channel. At the moment, this code randomly outputs one video on each page refresh:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var randNumber = RandNo(1,5);
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/tomdesigner777/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=5",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(result) {
            var data = result.data;
            
            $("#yt").html("<iframe width='560' height='315' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + data.items[randNumber].id + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
        }
    });
});

function RandNo(min,max) {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

The complete solution: http://jsfiddle.net/sbhomra/kCSsX/

Comment: See I'm new to the youtube API, and it really confuses me, I have no idea what they are talking about on it :S Thank you for the response though :)

Comment: @Tom Duffy: I'm trying to cook something up now for you. :-)

Comment: Really :) That would be great!

Comment: I forgot to add. You will need to add a jQuery Framework for this to work on your own page.